# Why does my .NET console app hang when waiting for Ctrl-C

Tags: c#, multithreading, console

I'm building a simple console app that starts up a timer and does some stuff. I want to close down if the user presses Ctrl-C.

When I code this up, the application detects the Ctrl-C but then hangs and never closes. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly AutoResetEvent _closeEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World - waiting for Ctrl-C");

            Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Got the Ctrl-C");
                _closeEvent.Set();
            };

            // Start up a timer and do work here...

            Console.WriteLine("Before WaitOne");
            _closeEvent.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("After WaitOne");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if this is just a side-effect of the Visual Studio debugger? If I run it without debugging then press Ctrl-C, the console then shows "Press any key to continue..." and pressing a key then terminates the application.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that the key to making this work is to set

```
eventArgs.Cancel = true;
```

inside the `CancelKeyPress` handler.

It all works nicely then, and the application terminates correctly.

Comment: This was the missing thing for me. Funny enough, when debugging in Rider, everything worked fine, but running in another console or debugging in Visual Studio, it did some strange things :)